# Performance - Good design : Should I use a trigger or use handle cases manually

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Suppose I have a table `Table1` that has a column `cardinal` that keeps track of the `COUNT()` of some other tables. When I remove a row in say `Table2`, I need to decrement the corresponding value in the column `cardinal`.

There are two solutions:

**1-** use an update each time after deleting the entry.

**2-** create a trigger to do the job

Which one is better considering performance, and best practice?
are there other better solutions?

**Context**: I have a table `forums` that keeps track on the number of posts in each forum. I need to decrement this number each time a post is deleted.

Comment: If you are not doing _hundreds_ of these per second, I call it "premature optimization".  Do whatever is more comfortable for you; rethink it in a few months.

Comment: For the moment, I don't think it's going to be 100 of these/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plan A (under, say, a million things to count):  Simply `COUNT(*)` when you need it.

Plan B: A `TRIGGER` would work.

Plan C (really big situations):  Don't keep the count in realtime; summarize periodically; then `SUM()` the Summary Table to get the up-to-the-last-hour (or whatever) tally.

Plan D (if C is not good enough):  Do C, and augment with A for the not-yet-tallied count.

Keep in mind...  For very large counts *and* very frequent requests for the count, the overhead of doing the count *may* impact the system enough to become a serious concern.